# Unable to install `sf `on R version 4.1.2

Tags: r, r-sf

I upgrade to R version 4.1.2 but now I cannot install `sf` package because the package it not available for this version of R supposedly

[image: R Console]

I downloaded the file from 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/sf_1.0-4.tgz' and try to install from a local file because when I tried to use `install.packages("sf")` the download timeout

[image: R Console 2]

Please could somebody provide some ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you install a package 'locally' you need to add `repos=NULL` (so, in your case `install.packages("~/Downloads/sf_1.0-4.tar", type = "source", repos = NULL)`). Your second error message indicates the package wasn't downloaded completely (it timed out). If you type `options(timeout = 600)` then try `install.packages("sf")` again it may work as expected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you please edit your question to include your console output as text rather than as images?

Comment: @jared_mamrot I tried ```options(timeout = 600)``` and then ```install.packages("sf")```  and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```r
install.packages(file.choose(), repos = NULL)
```

This will both (1) tell R that you are installing from a local file; (2) allow you to choose the file interactively, making sure that you're not making a mistake with the name or the extension.

I don't think you'll need `type = "source"` in this case, but it wouldn't hurt.

If you do need to install from source, be prepared for the fact that `sf` needs several external, system libraries:

> SystemRequirements:   C++11, GDAL (>= 2.0.1), GEOS (>= 3.4.0), PROJ (>=
> 4.8.0), sqlite3

It might be worth trying the installation from the repository again (possibly after setting `options(timeout = 600)` as suggested by @jared_mamrot) — it might be a transient problem — since that will skip any headaches with installing system libraries.

Comment: Normally I would disagree with file.choose but I think you're right and they might have messed up the actual extension so it could help in this case

Comment: @Ben Bolker  I tried ```options(timeout = 600``` and it worked. You are right better to avoid the headaches with installing system libraries. Thank you very much.